# While using Mist Browser(Test Network), am I also Mining blocks?

Tags: mist

My laptop heats up whenever I use Mist Browser application and my BDLDaemon(Bitdefender in Mac) is going crazy, taking up 4.15 GB of RAM.
So my question arises, Am I mining the blocks too?
 Which might be causing the heating issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by mining blocks. The only way you could start mining in my opinion is if you did an operation **like** miner.start(1). If you feel you are mining, just do miner.stop() in your javascript console. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Where do I write this command?

Comment: In your javascript console. However I doubt that this is the problem, because your console would be showing you mining operations. Like in the image I am attaching above.